# Double script error on mathematical formula

Tags: math-mode, errors

The formula is printed correctly

[image]

But I have this error for 6 times (I think it depends on the number of "f"):

```
Double subscript. ...al{f}\ped1\ped0+\mathnormal{f}\ped0\ped1}
```

I tried to look for a question to understand the error, but I could not find anything useful to understand the problem. Thanks in advance!
Here the code

```
\noindent \textbf{Accuratezza del modello} = $\frac{\text{Numero di predizioni corrette}}{\text{Numero totale di predizioni}} = \frac{\mathnormal{f}\ped1\ped1+\mathnormal{f}\ped0\ped0}{\mathnormal{f}\ped1\ped1+\mathnormal{f}\ped0\ped0+\mathnormal{f}\ped1\ped0+\mathnormal{f}\ped0\ped1}$
```

Comment: `\frac{f_{11}+f_{00}}{f_{11}+f_{00}+f_{10}+f_{01}}` Do you really think that `\mathnormal{f}` is necessary?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Such a formula should be displayed, to begin with; then `\mathnormal` is useless and `\ped` is a (wrong) command only defined for `babel-italian` and for *text mode* (LaTeX provides `\textsubscript`).

Math mode subscripts are introduced by `_`.

Do yourself a favor and forget about `\ped` and `\ap`.

```
\[
\textbf{Accuratezza del modello} = 
\frac{\text{Numero di predizioni corrette}}
     {\text{Numero totale di predizioni}} =
\frac{f_{11}+f_{00}}{f_{11}+f_{00}+f_{10}+f_{01}}
\]
```

Better yet, use `align*`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

Dimentica \verb|\ped| e \verb|\ap|; non avrebbero mai
dovuto essere definiti. Usa piuttosto la normale sintassi
\LaTeX{}
\begin{align*}
\textbf{Accuratezza del modello}
&= \frac{\text{Numero di predizioni corrette}}
        {\text{Numero totale di predizioni}} \\
&=\frac{f_{11}+f_{00}}{f_{11}+f_{00}+f_{10}+f_{01}}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In math formulas you should use `_` instead of `\ped`. (I guess that you use `\usepackage[italian]{babel}`.)

This should do the job for you:

```
\noindent \textbf{Accuratezza del modello} = $\frac{\text{Numero di predizioni corrette}}{\text{Numero totale di predizioni}} = \frac{\mathnormal{f}_{11}+\mathnormal{f}_{00}}{\mathnormal{f}_{11}+\mathnormal{f}_{00}+\mathnormal{f}_{10}+\mathnormal{f}_{01}}$
```